# Hot reloading in Angular Projects stopped working

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5, hot-reload

We have an Angular 4 application created through CLI which runs on its port (51000), but gets served from a node proxy running at port 52000, at url 52000/app (which would serve from 51000), whenever changes were made to the web app, the page reloading worked as expected from the proxy, i.e 52000/app, which get refreshed and new page is served.

After we **migrated** to Angular 5, the reloading stopped working across all developer machines, we verified our node tasks as well, but we couldn't find any changes that would affect the behavior.

This is same behavior on all dev boxes, test applications created on angular 5 reload just fine (without proxy).

Any ideas

Comment: ~I'd suggest not using HMR, it can cause issues with Angular. With the CLI it's usually fast enough to do a reload anyway~  
Ignore the above, I assumed "Hot reloading" intended to mean HMR

Comment: we are using CLI only, we are not using any explicit HMR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to resolve the issue by passing additional parameter, i.e. **public-host** to the CLI fixed the issue.

```
ng serve --port 51000 --aot --public-host http://localhost:52000/app/sockjs-node
```